# Create human task in WSO2 process server

Tags: wso2

I need to create human task in my BPEL process. But i couldn't find any tutorial in WSO2 to create human task. Can anyone suggest me some tutorial for this.

Answer (score -1):

This documentation will help you understand and create human task, http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Human+Tasks and http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Claims+Approval+Task+Sample

Comment: I already visited those pages, those page don't explain how we can create human task.